# NetBeans curly braces auto-closing

Tags: netbeans, formatting

In the last time I often initialize arrays in this form :

```
int[] test = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

When I type '[', NetBeans immediately put the closing brace.

The question is - which is the macro to do the same job with curly braces ?

Comment: Tools > Options, select Editor in toolbar, go for Code Completion tab. You will see that Insert Closing Brackets Automatically, now just Press Enter It will automatically add closing bracket,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select from menu **Tools** > **Options**, select **Editor** in toolbar, go for **Code Completion** tab.
You will see that **Insert Closing Brackets Automatically** is already automatically checked by default.

There was a guy, who asked an [analogical question](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-84753.html&highlight=)  a while ago. There was no helpful answer. I guess that means that we should look for that in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for solution too, for NetBeans 8.5  check answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338967/7162006, in same window is option:  **Completition Selectors For Java** add: {, autocomplete by hiting enter in editor. (classically)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for contributing. Your answer may be correct, if you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer you can see the guide lines for posting answers

Comment: When you hit enter after typing the opening curly brace, the one that closes is automatically added. Not before.

Answer (score 0):

**This macro work to me:**

Shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>

Macro code: `"}" caret-backward`