# I can't figure out how to disable Netbean's code completion without disabling pop-up of suggested code

Tags: java, netbeans, intellisense, preferences, code-completion

How do I disable code completion but keep suggestions enabled? Every time I type object.Method() without passing any parameters I get something similar to object.Method(datatype). Netbeans would complete the code after the first parenthesis, (. When I don't want to pass any parameters, I simply type ) once. I would get something like this thanks to auto complete: object.Method())

The null in between () would be replaced by the ) I typed.

I want to be able to **see suggested code without ctrl-space** and without having netbeans automatically insert the code for me. In netbeans I can disable the auto insertion of the second bracket } after I type the first {. I don't have an option to disable parentheses from auto inserting. The problem is that **if I disable code completion, I also disable the automatic pop-up that gives me related code**. Any advice?

Comment: I recommend switching to Eclipse. It's faster and much easier to use. NetBeans and me hate each other. It's a shame becuase it looks really well laid out: the way you have the facility to navigate to any method or variable in the left hand menu is great, but it's just a backwards stumbling oaf when it comes to doing anything useful. I know there are people who disagree, but I think Eclipse is *far* superior.

Comment: This answer did solve my problem. I can't upvote you because you submitted a comment instead of an answer. Also, it would have helped if you told me that Eclipse doesn't have this problem. I just switched to eclipse. The default settings are good. Why the hell does a tab insert four spaces instead of a regular tab in Netbeans? That's just horrendous.

Comment: lol. No idea. No probs. I'm glad that helped. As regards putting it as a comment, the thing is it doesn't answer your (main) question and in the past I've been criticised for submitting things which help but don't answer the question as answers. +1 on question and comment for being amusing, pointing out how yet another program has the uncanny ability to wrongfoot us at almost every move and pointing out how NetBeans yet again epicly fails the user friendliness test. It's an enemy of users

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the IDE to perform the project updates, you can disable the build analyzer as follows:

Right-click the project node in the Projects window and select Properties.
In the Project Properties dialog box, click the Code Assistance category.
Deselect the Use Build Analyzer option.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/HowTos.html

Answer (score -1):

It's been awhile since I used NetBeans (personally I prefer IntelliJ), but I believe you're using the wrong setting.  Try this: under Tools>Options>Editor>General, uncheck "Insert Closing Bracket Automatically".

See also this other question: [NetBeans curly braces auto-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717789/netbeans-curly-braces-auto-closing)

Comment: I am not using the wrong settings. I already disabled brackets. I already know about it. This doesn't disable the annoying auto insertion of parenthesis.